# Query SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

How do I convert this query into LINQ

```
SELECT Hotels.NameHotel AS 'Hotel', (SUM(Hotels.HotelID)/Hotels.HotelID) AS 'quantity' FROM ReservedRooms
INNER JOIN Rooms ON ReservedRooms.RoomID = Rooms.RoomID
INNER JOIN Hotels ON Rooms.HotelID = Hotels.HotelID
GROUP BY Hotels.NameHotel, Hotels.HotelID
```

To be more specific what I can not do is do the GROUP and SUM in the Select

Comment: Read something about LINQ, try it yourself and if you have troubles with the query get back here.

Comment: You can use tool to convert sql to linq..

Comment: `SUM(Hotels.HotelID)/Hotels.HotelID)` ?_?

Answer (score 2):

```
        var result = from rr in db.ReservedRooms
        join r in db.Rooms on rr.RoomID equal r.RoomID
        join h in db.Hotels on r.HotelID equal h.HotelID
        group by h by new {h.NameHotel, h.HotelID} into g
        select new 
        {
                Hotel = h.NameHotel,
                quantity = (g.Sum(SUM(h.HotelID))/h.HotelID)
        }
```